# MySQL и разные права доступа из интернета и на локалхосте

Tags: mysql

Создал пользователя в MySQL, разрешил доступ с любого хоста. Из интернета работает отлично. Устанавливаю программу на сервер с MySQL и получаю ошибку: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES). Что за ерунда? Как лечить?

Проверял mysql -u пускает с любым именем пользователя. А mysql -uuser -ppass уже не пускает.

Как сделать, чтобы из любого места был доступ по единому логину и паролю? Добавить копию этого пользователя, но с доступом только на localhost?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Вы добавили правило, которое позволяет всем пользователям заходить с `localhost`а без пароля. Что-то вроде:

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '%'@localhost;
```

Посмотрите таблицу `users` в базе `mysql` и проверьте соответствие пользователей и паролей.

Для лучшего понимания стоит обратиться к официальной документации, ну или хотя бы вот [сюда](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Adding_users.html)

Comment: Не добавлял. MySQL устанавливается с этими правилами. Удалил этих пользователей, все заработало как надо.